# how to encode a binary file in a rails controller, and then decode it in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, base64

I am trying to build a function where I can let users upload images from their phone, while on their desktop browsers.  They basically scan a QR code, upload the file, and then rails sends that file back to their form, where they can they preview, and submit the form.  Everything works except I cannot "unescape" an escaped file without it messing up.  A PDF for example almost works but it gets garbled.

In the controller, I'm doing:

```
@file_payload = escape_javascript(Base64.encode64(File.read(@file_path)))
```

That gets sent down to javascript via a js.erb file, and in that js.erb file I do

```
file = new File([atob("<%= @file_payload %>")], '<%= @file_path.split("/").last %>', {
    type: 'text/plain',
    lastModified: new Date(),
});
dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.items.add(file);
input = $("input[data-id='<%= @datum_id %>'][type='file']");
input[0].files = dataTransfer.files;
```

The problem appears to be this line:

```
file = new File([atob("<%= @file_payload %>")], '<%= @file_path.split("/").last %>', {
    type: 'text/plain',
    lastModified: new Date(),
});
```

specifically

```
atob("<%= @file_payload %>")
```

Going in, I do 2 encodings, Base64 encode, then escape_javascript, on the way back, I do atob - I speculate that if I could reverse escape_javascript in javascript, this would work.

Does anyone know how to do this, or can you suggest another way to encode a binary file in the controller that can be passed through to javascript?

Thanks,
Kevin

UPDATE

It looks like the original file, since it's binary, is not utf-8 compatible, so it can be base64 encoded in Ruby, but when base64 decoded in Javascript, it's not an exact replica.  So what I really need is a Ruby encoding method that can be Javascript decoded that supports non-UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Maybe try `File.binread(@file_path)` or `File.read(@file_path,'rb')`? This will deal with the file as ASCII-8BIT rather than UTF-8.  Not sure why the `escape_javascript` is needed here.

Comment: The reason it's needed is because it's inside an .js.erb and without it, the javascript chokes, but I will give this a shot

Comment: no luck, it chokes without escape_javascript (it dies silently (I find .js.erb's the hardest to debug)

Comment: i think the root cause is the UTF-8 issue, updating the original post

Comment: binread did not fix the issue, and if i encode it in ruby, i need to decode it in javascript, i cannot find a way to (read a binary, encode it, then base64 it) in ruby, and then (de-base-64 it, de-encode it, convert it back to binary) in javascript

Comment: but how do you transfer it from a rails controller to the DOM so it can be used in javascript without base64 encoding?

Comment: @user1130176 I wasn't recommending removing the encoding I was recommending reading the file as binary and encoding the binary e.g. `Base64.encode64(File.binread(@file_path))`